# Intellij Idea and auto formatting : spaces

Tags: intellij-idea, code-formatting

I noticed Intellij Idea auto formatting removes spaces from blank lines. In an example below spaces are shown with "_"

```
__line1
__
__line3
```

And idea makes that:

```
__line1

__line3
```

How can I turn that off? It prevents using subversion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is found under:

- Windows: `File > Settings > Editor > General > Strip trailing spaces on Save`
- MacOS: `IntelliJ IDEA > Preferences > Editor > General > Strip trailing spaces on Save`

IntelliJ gives you the ability to search in the Preferences dialog. You can narrow down the list of options by searching for "trailing", for example.

[image: Strip trailing spaces on Save Dialog]

Comment: @PhilipRego, the settings/preferences are going to be in slightly different locations depending on your OS.

Comment: 2021 update. Now it's a checkbox. On a sidenote, this only works on **save**, not on reformat.

Answer (score 3):

#### IntelliJ IDEA 15

File > Settings... > Editor > **General** > Strip trailing spaces on Save: None

[image: Strip Trailing spaces]